# Adding minutes to string variable containing date

Tags: bash, date, time

I have string from log file containing date that looks like `12-02-2018 05:19` (`%d-%m-%Y %H:%M` format).

I need to increment the minute value by 1.

For example:

$end contains 12-02-2018 05:21

```
add=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" --date="$end") 
echo $add  
date: invalid date `12-02-2018 05:21`
```

How do I add the minute?

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the date itself in another way so that the date command can parse it. That can be accomplished by sed. Then you can output it the way you like:

```
#!/bin/bash
v="12-02-2018 05:19"
dt=$(echo $v | sed -re 's#(..)-(..)-(....) (..:..)()#\3-\2-\1 \4:00#')
date -d "$dt +1 min" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"
```

Comment: I literally told the date command the format of the string though, +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"  

RIIIIIIIIIIIGHT ok the format shapes the _output_ it doesn't describe the _input_

Thanks!

Comment: Ok this works great, however: date interprets the input as 12 hour. Logs are in 24 hour. So when I have an input of 05:21 (obviously AM) date converts the output to 17:22, because I have the output as 24 hour, which is the same as the input! date is by default expecting input to be formatted in 12hour for some reason

Comment: On my system it interprets the time as 24 hour. Perhaps it has to do with the current timezone (see value of TZ environment variable):

    `TZ="Europe/Berlin" date -d "2018-02-21 05:19 +1 min" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"`
and 
    `TZ="GST-5" date -d "2018-02-21 05:19 +1 min" +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"`

produce different results...